# BASH: get data from MySQL where records have spaces

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to get values from a MySQL database, for a later substitution with perl, everything works fine but if a record contain space " " the variables will be set uncorrectly.

Example if in the database I have:

- sede = "street"
- fede = "calvin and hobbes"
- lede = "12"

the result for the variables will be:

- $TAGSEDE = "steet"
- $TAGFEDE = "calvin"
- $TAGLEDE = "and"

I understood there is something wrong in setting $DBDATAF but, I can't identify it (english isn't my mother language so some misunderstanding are more than a possibility).

```
DBDATAF=$(mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -se "USE $DBNAME; SELECT sede, fede, lede FROM $DBTABL WHERE cf='$CFPI'")

read TAGSEDE TAGFEDE TAGLEDE <<< $DBDATAF



/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s/TAGDATAINSERT/$TAGDATAINSERT/g" $i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code breaks down for two reasons:

1. When `$DBDATAF` is passed to the `<<<` operator, the tabs are discarded. To keep them, double quote the variable as shown below.
2. `read` separates the input line into words using the `IFS` special variable. By default, it separates on tab, space or newline. So even though tabs are now preseved when passed to `<<<`, the `read` command splits on spaces also. Setting `IFS` to a tab makes `read` split as desired. Putting the IFS assignment and `read` on one line ensures that `IFS` returns to the default after read exits

```
IFS="$( echo -e '\t' )" read TAGSEDE TAGFEDE TAGLEDE <<< "$DBDATAF"
```

Comment: Explanation: The OPs code breaks down in the `read` call for 2 reasons: 1. When `$DBDATAF` is passed to the `<<<` operator tabs are discarded. To keep them double quote the variable as shown above. 2. `read` separates the input line into words using the IFS special variable which by default separates on tab, space or newline. So even though tabs are now preseved when passed to `<<<` the `read` command splits on spaces also. Setting IFS to only use tab characters gets around this. Finally, putting the IFS assignment and read on one line ensures that IFS returns to the default after read exits

Comment: Thanks, @benrifkah. Incorporated your comment into my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, clear and smooth! using IFS reading one line is perfect. Works also with 20 variables to read.